# How to use sample ASMX service added in my project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, soap

I have added asmx web service in my project using Connected Services in Visual Studio 2017. Proxy is generated properly. This is the URL `http://secure.smartbearsoftware.com/samples/testcomplete10/webservices/Service.asmx?WSDL` . I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0.

How can I use the service in my controller. I want to call HelloWorld. I try to create instance but no success. Anyone?

I tried like `var service = new SampleWebServiceSoapClient();` . That's the Question. How?

Comment: If you ask for help on not working code then minimum expected by you is to show the code that is not working. I suggest to read [ask]

Comment: @steve, Well there is no code to show. All I want is to call the service like I tried var service = new SampleWebServiceSoapClient(); etc . That's what I am asking. How to use it?

Comment: What do you mean by "no success"? Compile error? Runtime error?

Comment: @crowcoder , Please check my comment on first error.

Comment: If you mean the first answer, then what arguments does the constructor ask for? Can you provide them?

Comment: @crowcoder, I don't know. It would be easy if you add the service and try please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to simply require an enumeration that states the SOAP version you want to use:

```
var client = new ServiceReference1.SampleWebServiceSoapClient(EndpointConfiguration.SampleWebServiceSoap12);
var res = await client.HelloWorldAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

However, I'm not sure about the support for System.ServiceModel in Core 2.0. Don't they have a modern API?

> Update

It works with this NuGet package: System.ServiceModel.Http

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's what I was looking for. What do you mean by Modern API?

Comment: I mean a RESTful service that typically accepts and responds with JSON. ASMX is oooooold school at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you might be looking for.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var client = new ServiceReference1.SampleWebServiceSoapClient();
        string result = client.HelloWorld();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right. I already tried but there is error says "SampleWebServiceSoapClient does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments" .